# iis7 multiple websites visible in localhost on my server, but only one visible online

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I've got a web server (windows server 2008 R2) with IIS7.5, bought on telecity,com, where I have access via remote desktop; on this server I had a website in production, accessible via IP (at the moment I don't have a domain) and now I'd like to add a testing environment, so I've configured another website on another port (8888), and I've created an application on the folder containing test files.

Now, when I try to browse this new website on the server using localhost address (http://localhost:8888) all works fine, but if I try to browse it using public IP (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888) it doesn't work.

The strange thing is that the "production" website works well both on localhost and on web.

Do you have some hints or suggestions? I'm going nuts on this!!

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Comment: I presume you are on a home broadband connection so maybe your ISP doesn't let you host web pages and blocks Port 8888.

Or maybe your firewall blocks Port 8888/http

Comment: this isn't an homemade server, is a VPS.. sorry if I didn't mentioned before...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know where I can check for this firewall... I've checked windows firewall but I don't see any restriction on that port...

Comment: Then i dont find any other issue. Double check your IP. :(

Comment: as I told, this IP works for "production" website, but not for testing one... the strange thing is that I've added a ftp access (port 8821) on this testing website, and it works... It's really strange, and my VPS service provider don't answer me...

Comment: sometimes solution is so easy... I wrote a wrong firewall rule, on wrong port... thanks a lot

Comment: what happens exactly when you try to load the page? Are you getting a server error?